# Aligning output in Linux paste command

Tags: linux, output, columns

How can I make the second file in a paste start in the same spot regardless of the length of the line in the first file? For example:

```
file1:
small
incredibly humungous

file 2:
A
B
```

I want paste file1 file2 to output:

```
small                        A
incredibly humungous         B
```

instead of:

```
small                        A
incredibly humungous                        B
```

Answer (score 6):

We can use the `column` command with `tab` as the delimiter.

`paste file1 file2 | column -s $'\t' -t`

```
small                 A
incredibly humungous  B
```

Answer (score 0):

`paste` inserts a tab characters between the contents of the pasted files.  We can use that to parse the result into `awk` and print the columns with a custom `printf` formatting.

The pipe characters in the output below are just for decoration.

Right-justified 25+5 characters:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk -F '\t' '{ printf("|%25s|%5s|\n", $1, $2) }'
|                    small|    A|
|     incredibly humungous|    B|
```

Left-justified 25+5 characters:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk -F '\t' '{ printf("|%-25s|%-5s|\n", $1, $2) }'
|small                    |A    |
|incredibly humungous     |B    |
```

Too short first column, left-justified 5+5 characters:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk -F '\t' '{ printf("|%-5s|%-5s|\n", $1, $2) }'
|small|A    |
|incredibly humungous|B    |
```

Too short first column with truncation of data, left-justified 5+5 characters:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk -F '\t' '{ printf("|%-5.5s|%-5s|\n", $1, $2) }'
|small|A    |
|incre|B    |
```

Figuring out the longest line in `file1` and `file2` and using that as the field width in the `printf()` call:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk -F '\t' -v len=$( awk -F '\t' 'length > m { m = length } END { print m }' file1 file2 ) '{ printf("|%*s|%*s|\n", len, $1, len, $2 ) }'
|               small|                   A|
|incredibly humungous|                   B|
```

Same thing, but for the two columns separately:

```
$ longest_line() { awk -F '\t' 'length > m { m = length } END { print m }' "$1"; }
$ paste file1 file2 | awk -F '\t' -v len1=$( longest_line file1 ) -v len2=$( longest_line file2 ) '{ printf("|%*s|%*s|\n", len1, $1, len2, $2 ) }'
|               small|A|
|incredibly humungous|B|
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not paste, but I think lam is the tool you want.

```
lam  -f-30 file1 file2
```

```
small                         A
incredibly humungous          B
```